# Excel VBA Regex

Tags: excel, vba

I need help extracting the following highlighted items delimited by **REGEX**

`"delimeter is "YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD-CM""`

```
Sub test()
    Dim strg, text_string As String
    text_string1 = "**mmmmm-02**-20141027-06240105-CM-STATS-HOURLY-DATA-perf.xlsx"
    text_string2 = "**mmmm-mmmm-02**-20140811-12010069-CM-HOURLY-STATS-perf.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly need to be extracted? Do you mean "YYYYMMDD....." needs to be extracted from both the text_strings ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim text_string1 As String, myResult As String

text_string1 = "**mmmmm-02**-20141027-06240105-CM-STATS-HOURLY-DATA-perf.xlsx"

   With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") '// Create Regex Engine
     .Pattern = "[\d]{8}[\-][\d]{8}[\-]CM" '// Set match pattern
      If .Test(text_string1) Then myResult = .Execute(text_string1)(0) '// If found return result.
   End With

End Sub
```